# Problema com Wp Query

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

estou com um problema no loop na hora que faço um wp_query. Veja meu codigo:

```
$query_video = new WP_Query( $args );
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'videos',
    'posts_per_page' => '4',
    'orderby' => 'rand'
);

<?php if( $query_video->have_posts()) : while( $query_video->have_posts()) : $query_video->the_post(); ?>
```

O que eu estou querendo fazer:

- Trazer apenas 4 posts aleatorios da categoria Videos.
- Essa categoria Videos é do tipo Post-Format Video ( creio eu que isso não influencia muito, pois estou querendo trazer tudo da categoria videos.

Só que ele não está mostrando meu loop! Poderia me da um Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que carregar a variável $args antes de criar um novo WP_Query. É só trocar a ordem e colocar $args e depois $query_videos.